# Why my database is cleared every time I hot restart my application? I need to change my database version every time

Tags: android, database, flutter, sqlite

```
class DbHelper {
  static Database? _db;
  static const String dbName = 'tournament_host.db';
 
*here is my database initialization*
  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if ( _db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return null;
  }

  initDb() async {

*Path to my database*

    var databasePath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join( databasePath.path, dbName);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 4, onCreate: _createDb);
    return db;
  }
```

Comment: You want to update the database version on every hot restart?

Comment: No , I want the data that I inserted previously without changing the version.